# The array index doesnt show the character

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char s1[30] = "This is a sentence";

    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(s1);i++){
        if(s1[i] = ' '){
            printf("+");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to loop the array to find all the spaces this happens:

```
Output: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ //30 pluses.
```

Why doesnt my program outputs 3 pluses?

EDIT: My problem was a simply typo mistake, If you didn't understand what is wrong here take a look at accepted answer.

Comment: Comparison is `==` not `=`, turn on compiler warnings

Comment: @Slava Oh, thank you I am using the online compiler. I didnt see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your conditional statement, you're *assigning* space to `s[ i ]` (`operator =`). You want to compare them (`operator ==`).

Try

```
if (s[ i ] == ' ')
```

`s[ i ] = ' '` is always true because the result of an assignment is the value assigned (space). This value is implicitly converted to a `bool` (`0` = `false`, anything else = `true`). Since a space is `32` in ASCII, it will always be `true`.

**References** - [Assignment Operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment), [Comparison Operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), [ASCII Table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)

Answer (score 4):

Change `=` to `==` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if(s1[i] == ' '){
   printf("+");
}
```

`=` is an assignment operator. To compare two value you need to use `==` operator. You have used `=` that that assignment operator always return true so `+` is being printed out all the time.